# How to use exec command to pass both int and char *const args[] to main?

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to use the exec family of Unix commands to execute a C program from within another program.

The target file's main function is defined as

```
int main(int argc, char *const argv[])
```

But the exec commands only seem to take the arguments of

```
const char *path, char *const argv[]
```

How then do I pass the int value to this function? Would it be valid to include it as the first value of `argv` even though `argv` is meant to take char values and not ints?

Comment: See http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve: `Both argv and envp must be terminated by a NULL pointer`. The number of arguments `argc` is then automatically determined.

Answer (score 6):

The `int argc` is passed automatically by the executable loader. It is calculated by finding the first occurrence of a `NULL` pointer in the `argv` array.

When creating the argument vector for your exec call always make sure that the last element in it is a `NULL` pointer. e.g.

```
char * argv[] = {"cat", "test.txt", NULL};
```